# Laravel assets url

Tags: image, url, laravel, assets

I have installed Laravel and began trying to write an app. I made some directories for my assets in the same directory as /app. But when I try to visit an image in my localhost for example:  `http://localhost/assets/images/image.png`

I've also tried it on: `http://localhost/app/assets/images/image.png`

I ran into the problem when I was trying to set a background image in a view, and it kept going to 404.

This is what my app looks like under app/

```
->app
->assets
->commands
->config
->controllers
->database
->lang
->models
->start
->storage
->tests
->views
app.txt
routes.php
filters.php
```

But I get errors about requests. I have double checked that the url is correct.

```
Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException
```

Comment: Your assets (and anything else that needs to be hit by a browser directly) need to go in the public/ directory as this should be the document root. The app/ folder is shouldn't be accessible to a browser.

Answer (score 78):

You have to put all your assets in `app/public` folder, and to access them from your views you can use `asset()` helper method.

Ex. you can retrieve `assets/images/image.png` in your view as following:

`<img src="{{asset('assets/images/image.png')}}">`

Comment: The syntax {{asset()}} does not work in my case at all. I am using 

background: url('{{asset('assets/images/image.png')}}')

This does not work at all lol. Php syntax errors. Not sure why I keep seeing that syntax when it always returns errors in every context

Comment: It's not `url('{{asset('assets/images/image.png')}})` !!, curly brackets `{{ 'some string'}}` means `<?php echo 'some string' ?>` in blade template engine, and you don't have to call `url` function, `asset` function will return a valid url to your image, please try the exact code in my post above without adding anything.

Comment: and don't forget to put all assets in `app/public/assets` folder.

Comment: @MohammadWalid It's an old comment, I know, but I thought I'd point out that @vikingcode was reffering to the CSS function `url()`. As in, he is echoing this into a `style="{{}}"` attribute.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but if I need this in innerHTML?
<img src="{{asset('assets/images/image.png')}}">

Answer (score 6):

You have to do two steps:

1. Put all your files (css,js,html code, etc.) into the public folder.
2. Use `url({{ URL::asset('images/slides/2.jpg') }})` where `images/slides/2.jpg` is path of your content.

Similarly you can call js, css etc.

Answer (score 4):

Besides put all your assets in the *public* folder, you can use the `HTML::image()` Method, and only needs an argument which is the path to the image, relative on the public folder, as well:

```
{{ HTML::image('imgs/picture.jpg') }}
```

Which generates the follow HTML code:

```
<img src="http://localhost:8000/imgs/picture.jpg">
```

The link to other elements of `HTML::image()` Method: http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/185/generating-an-html-image-element

Answer (score 0):

{{ asset('js/jquery.min.js') }}
//Full Path http://127.0.0.1:8000/images/slides/2.jpg
Do Not Add Public folder name

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).